# Is it ok to initialize all classes inside the Main class?

Tags: java, class, initialization, program-entry-point

Recently i started working on one of my first bigger projects and i noticed more classes start to pile up
I never had more than 3 to 4 classes before and i was wondering if there's some sort of downside to initialize all the classes and create the getters for each instance of those classes inside the Main one.

```
DatabaseClass db;
Commands cmds;
Configuration configuration;
public Configuration getConfiguration() { return configuration; }
public Commands getCommandsClass() { return cmds; }
public DatabaseClass getDatabaseClass() { return db; }
//Inside of some sort of method
    db = new DatabaseClass(this);
    cmds = new Commands(this);
    events = new Configuration(this);
```

And then i create the new Objects inside some sort of method.
Is this a wrong approach?
Is there any better way to handle this?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: You are creating a god object.

Comment: Follow up to what Johannes mentioned above: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object

Comment: This is definitly useful as i never heard of the "God object" concept before, many things to learn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following a hierarchical structure, using responsibilities as a guide.

The main class is going to be responsible for initializing the high-level objects of the application, but you should keep each object with the class that has the knowledge to initialize and operate it.

This is a deep topic, but definitely a workable skill.
Look for the GRASP patterns as a guide (GRASP stands for General Responsibility Assignment Software Principles/Patterns), there is a good wikipedia entry on it.

Comment: Thank you sir, seems like the Creator Pattern entry from wikipedia helped me bunch understand when and where i should initialize those objects.
I'll leave a link for future people that might stumble into this thread.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRASP_(object-oriented_design)

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is the most basic way of declaring objects and this wilil definitely lead to problem in future. One problem is, it cannot be testable.

Q: Is it ok to initialize all classes inside the Main class?

A: The short Answer is "NO".

Then where do we initialise them?

That depends upon your project requirements and the kind of design pattern that you have applied.

You can have a look at : https://www.javatpoint.com/design-patterns-in-java

Comment: Thank you for the response and the guide link, i'm looking to improve and this is just what i need.